# assign $attributes in nested Laravel 7 blade components

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-views

With Laravel 7, I began to use **View Components**.
I am trying to pass the `$attributes` variable from one component to another like:

**x-modal component:**

```
<div {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'modal fade']) }}>
   Something great...
</div>
```

**x-modal-form component:**

```
<x-modal {{ $attributes }}>
    Something great too
</x-modal>
```

In this case, I have an **id** property in the x-modal component like:

```
<x-modal-form id="aRandomId" title="Test"></x-modal-form>
```

But in this case, the id **aRandomId** is not spread to the x-modal component. I have an error "*syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF), expecting end of file*" because of *{{ $attributes }}*

Do you know how to do that?

Comment: you want to repeat id in same view ?!

Comment: I use a component in an other component, and I want to spread the id to the deapest one

Answer (score 1):

This behavior has been fixed in Laravel 8: [#32576](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/32576)

You can now pass the `$attributes` variable from one component to another

Answer (score 0):

as per laravel [documents](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#managing-attributes) :

> All of the attributes that are not part of the component's constructor
> will automatically be added to the component's "attribute bag". This
> attribute bag is automatically made available to the component via the
> $attributes variable. All of the attributes may be rendered within the
> component by echoing this variable.

and in case of nested or use more than component in one view and want to use attribute bag so you put in this bag the common attribute and put manually unique attribute like so:

```
<x-modal {{ $attributes }}>
    <x-modal-form {{ $attributes }} id="aRandomId" title="Test">
     // code here
    </x-modal-form>
</x-modal>
```

and of course, The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element. The value of the id attribute must be unique within the HTML document.